# merge columns: merge on column has truncated digits

Tags: r, merge

I need to merge to data frames on a common column `ID_key`. A problem is that for one of the tables, the column `ID_key` has had the last digits truncated.

```
dataframe_a: ID_key     dataframe_b: ID_key
1002                    10020000000    
1002                    10020000000  
1002                    10020000000 
1002                    10020000000 
32410001                32410001001 
32410001                32410001001 
32410001                32410001001
```

End result would be that dataframe_a and dataframe_b merge on column ID_key.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge" columns here?  Can you also include what the output should look like?

Comment: Take a look at `stringdist_join` and `regex_join` from the fuzzyjoin-package.

Comment: Based on this example, we could just take the first 4 characters and merge as usual.

Comment: you mean to make another column of just the first four numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regexpr` and `regmatches` to truncate the `ID_key` from *dataframe_b* to those found in *dataframe_b* and then use `merge`.

```
dataframe_b$ID_key_tr  <- regmatches(dataframe_b$ID_key, regexpr(paste0("^", unique(dataframe_a$ID_key), collapse = "|"),  dataframe_b$ID_key))
dataframe_b
#       ID_key ID_key_tr
#1 10020000000      1002
#2 10020000000      1002
#3 10020000000      1002
#4 10020000000      1002
#5 32410001001  32410001
#6 32410001001  32410001
#7 32410001001  32410001

merge(dataframe_a, dataframe_b, by.x="ID_key", by.y="ID_key_tr")
```

Data:

```
dataframe_a <- data.frame(ID_key=c("1002","1002","1002","1002","32410001","32410001","32410001"))
dataframe_b <- data.frame(ID_key=c("10020000000","10020000000","10020000000","10020000000","32410001001","32410001001","32410001001"))
```